# Error when reading S3 data with Spark using Iceberg: "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm encountering an issue when trying to read data from an S3 bucket using Spark (PySpark) with Iceberg. I have configured my Spark application with the following configs:

```py
...
conf.set("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.4_2.12:1.3.1,org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-extensions-3.4_2.12:1.3.1,software.amazon.awssdk:bundle:2.20.145,software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client:2.20.145")
conf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions")
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog")
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type", "hive")
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO")
...
```

However, I'm consistently having the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o82.sql.
: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. (Service: S3, Status Code: 301, Request ID: ..., Extended Request ID: ...)
```

I suspect that this error is related to a misconfigured region, and I've tried to address it by setting the Spark configuration properties like this:

```py
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.region", "eu-west-1")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.region", "eu-west-1")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.region", "eu-west-1")
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.hadoop.fs.s3.region", "eu-west-1")
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.hadoop.fs.s3a.region", "eu-west-1")
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.hadoop.fs.s3n.region", "eu-west-1")
```

However, this doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can properly configure the Spark application to access the S3 bucket with the correct endpoint?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved the issue by changing the default region name using the `aws configure` command on my local machine. After making this change, my Spark application successfully accessed the S3 bucket without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

the setting for the s3a connector is `fs.s3a.endpoint.region`; change that

1. don't be afraid to read the [s3a documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html) for the official docs.
2. even that can be a bit wrong. the file [Constants.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/Constants.java) is the normative definition of option names